# after enctype="multipart/form-data" request not working

Tags: java, jsp, servlets

```
public class Relay extends HttpServlet {   
    @Override
    public void service(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
    throws ServletException, IOException {
        String command = request.getParameter("command");
        RequestDispatcher rd =request.getRequestDispatcher(command);
        rd.forward(request, response);
        System.out.println("Request forwarded to " + command + " servlet");
    }
}
```

This is my Relay servlet, I'm sending data from this form

```html
<form action="Relay" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data"> /
    <input type="hidden" name="command" value="AddProduct" />
    <input type="text" name="pname" value="" />
    <input name="" type="submit" value="Add Product">
</form>
```

It is throwing a `java.lang.NullPointerException`.

But works fine when I remove this:

```html
enctype="multipart/form-data"
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Why do you need to add it then? Just keep it out.

If you need it in order to upload a file by `<input type="file">` which you intend to add later on, then you should put `@MultipartConfig` annotation on your servlet, so that `request.getParameter()` will work and that all uploaded files can be retrieved by `request.getPart()`.

```
@WebServlet("/Relay")
@MultipartConfig
public class Relay extends HttpServlet {   
    // ...
}
```

#### See also:

- [How to upload files to server using JSP/Servlet?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2422468/how-to-upload-files-to-server-using-jsp-servlet/2424824#2424824)

Comment: That's a different problem, unrelated to the way how the form is submitted. If you need help, press `Ask Question`. You only need to be really more elaborate on the problem than just saying "not working". Investigate and describe the problem in developer's perspective, not in enduser's perspective. Perhaps the (relative) path was just plain wrong?

Comment: i mean when i add '@WebServlet("/Relay")' '@MultipartConfig' to relay servlet forward it but porblem is file upload is not working List items = uploadHandler.parseRequest(request); this is how i'm getting request

Comment: Huh? Why are you using commons file upload instead of `request.getPart()`? You don't need commons file upload at all if you're already using the Servlet 3.0 `@MultipartConfig`. Please read the "See also" link once again carefully.

Comment: I did nowhere state in the answer that you should be using commons file upload. I said that you just need to put the `@MultipartConfig` annotation on the servlet and then use `request.getPart()` to obtain the file. That's all. The linked answer contains a more elaborate example of using `request.getPart()`.

Comment: @BalusC how to handle this if i'm using 2.5 version and not 3.0

Comment: @jasmeet24: I don't post links for decoration only. Click them if you want to learn more.

Answer (score 1):

Parameters encoded with `multipart/form-data` are sent in POST body - not as regular request parameters, therefore can't be read using `request.getParamter(...)`.

Check out [Commons file upload](http://commons.apache.org/fileupload/apidocs/org/apache/commons/fileupload/package-summary.html) package for multipart requests processing.

Comment: Your first phrase makes no sense. Also without `multipart/form-data`, the data is still sent in request body (this is controlled by `method="post"`, not by `enctype`). It's just differently encoded. The default encoding is `name1=value1&name2=value2&name3=value3`, however with `multipart/form-data` there are multiple blocks, each with its own headers, separated by a boundary. For an example, see [RFC2388](http://www.faqs.org/rfcs/rfc2388.html).

Answer (score 0):

I am including this just for additional information for troubleshooting.
if you are stuck and want to know about what all parameters are coming through multipart request you can print all parameters using following code.

```
MultipartRequest multi = <Your code to retrieve multipart request goes here. Sorry but can not post code as I use proprietary APIs>  

Enumeration en1 = multi.getParameterNames();
        while (en1.hasMoreElements()) { 
            String strParamName = (String)en1.nextElement(); 
            String[] strParamValues = multi.getParameterValues(strParamName); 

            for (int i = 0; i < strParamValues.length; i++) { 
            System.out.println(strParamName + "=" + strParamValues[i]); 
            } 

        }
```

Answer (score -1):

remove the form tag and use

```
echo <?php form_open_multipart('Controller/function');
```

I got the same issue whenever I use `enctype="multipart/form-data"`
I didn't get the file name and when I remove that it was working fine
try it it worked for me